# A group of six reactions

Tags: riddle

There exists a group of six reactions to six intended valid actions. Only one of those reactions can act as a valid action as well. When that reaction acts as an intended valid action, there is a possibility of the reaction being the same as the action.

***What are those six reactions?***

---

Hint 1:

> The intended valid action changes every midnight but the group of six reactions remains the same!

---

Hint 2:

> Green, Yellow and Grey.

Comment: After justforplaylists's answer I think the question is too generic.  There is no indication of where to search.  Every action leads to a reaction.  To solve it one has to brainstorm and hope to get the same idea as you had.  So: clue please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this refers to

> WORDLE, known for its green/yellow/gray squares.

The 6 actions refers to the fact that you get

> Up to 6 tries to make a word.

The 6 valid reactions are:

> 1: Genius 2: Magnificent 3: Impressive 4: Splendid 5: Great 6: Phew, which you get depending on the number of tries.

Note that only one of these is a valid action:

> GREAT - and there is a small possibility it was the intended valid action (actual answer).

There are other reactions:

> Not in word list  / you lost (or similar)
>  But those are not reactions to *valid* actions. A valid action is a winning guess.

Comment: Nice, I had this in mind but didn't know about the  different reactions.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be describing

> sabre fencing

so the six actions are

> attack, riposte, counter-attack, redouble, remise, reprise

and the six reactions are

> tierce, quarte, quinte, prime, seconde, counter-attack

assuming I'm interpreting Wikipedia correctly and we don't count

> sixte, septime, octave, neuvieme

as separate.

Comment: Not what I had in my mind. The answer you've given is completely new to me and very interesting. The answer to my riddle is much more simpler and can be answered by majority of people. There exists six and only six reactions.